# Refactor Logic using DRY principles

Tags: c++, compare, dry

While programming in C++ I stumbled across source code like this:

```
int enemy = 1; //enemy can be 1 or -1
if (enemy == 1) {
    for (short i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if (some_array[i] <= enemy) {
            cout << i << ", ";
            do_sth(i);
        }
    }
} else if (enemy == -1) {
    for (short i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        if (some_array[i] >= enemy) {
            cout << i << ", ";
            do_sth_else_here(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Without doubts, the code does what it should, but is against [*DRY*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) and messy as well.

Is there a way to **shorten** the code (e.g. swapping the greater than to a lesser than when `enemy` is **negative**) or refactoring it to fit the DRY principle better?

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Forgot a semicolon ;) I assign the enemy int otherwise usually :D

Comment: There are several ways this code can be refactored, and which is best would be a matter of opinion and other circumstances. This isn't a good fit for stack overflow.

Comment: If `enemy` can be `1` or `-1` why do you have `else if(...)`?

Comment: @mah I understand your doubts. Anyway, having a solution which would fit the DRY principle a bit better wouldn't be opinion-based.

Comment: @WeatherVane Sanity check. I just simplified it for the example.

Comment: So what is the point of asking how to improve code, if it isn't your code?

Comment: @WeatherVane Why you have doubt's that this *is* my code (it is btw.). I just gave an example because I've seen such code-structeres a lot recently

Comment: if enemy has two possible states, isn't the obvious next step to refactor it to be a bool, or an enum?

Comment: @RichardHodges That's a step in the right direction, but in the end it's just "fine tuning". The main focus lies on the if/else if here.

Comment: so you'd like some kind of policy based approach?

Comment: @RichardHodges If it's necessary, yes. I'm just looking for a "cleaner" way than an if/else condition, because if I'd expand the code I'd repeat myself. As stated in my question another approach could be to "swap" the greater than to a lesser than depending on the sign of the int

Comment: @manniL template-based answer provided. We could go further but I think we'd start to lose in clarity what we gained in DRYness.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107356/discussion-between-richard-hodges-and-mannil).

Comment: @manniL Couldn't help myself. There is now a super-DRY solution in part 2 of the answer.

Comment: @manniL "write me something that adheres to DRY" is not exactly opinion based, but it's not exactly the opposite either (because there are multiple ways to write it). The real issue at that point becomes: despite there being some people that are happy to take on such a request, it's off topic and inappropriate for stack overflow. It might be very much on topic for codereview.stackexchange.com or some other site in the SE network, I'm not sure... but it's not appropriate here.

Comment: @mah [codereview.se] only allows questions posted by an author or maintainer of the code.

Comment: @200_success It is my code indeed :D So it'd fit there quite well as mah said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we could reasonably reduce the function to something like this without losing too much readability:

## First Attempt

```
void handle_enemy(int enemy)
{
    assert(enemy == -1 or enemy == 1);
    if (enemy == 1) {
        check_enemy(enemy, std::less_equal<>(), &do_sth);
    } else if (enemy == -1) {
        check_enemy(enemy, std::greater_equal<>(), &do_sth_else_here);
    }
}
```

Where `check_enemy` has been refactored to:

```
template<class Comparer, class Action>
void check_enemy(int enemy, Comparer comp, Action action)
{
    for (short i = 1; i < some_array.size(); i++) {
        if (comp(some_array[i], enemy))
        {
            std::cout << i;
            action(i);
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Full working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

void do_sth(int i) { std::cout << '!' ; }
void do_sth_else_here(int i) { std::cout << '?'; }

std::array<int, 100> some_array;

template<class Comparer, class Action>
void check_enemy(int enemy, Comparer comp, Action action)
{
    for (short i = 1; i < some_array.size(); i++) {
        if (comp(some_array[i], enemy))
        {
            std::cout << i;
            action(i);
            std::cout << ", ";
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void handle_enemy(int enemy)
{
    assert(enemy == -1 or enemy == 1);
    if (enemy == 1) {
        check_enemy(enemy, std::less_equal<>(), &do_sth);
    } else if (enemy == -1) {
        check_enemy(enemy, std::greater_equal<>(), &do_sth_else_here);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine eng(std::random_device{}());
    std::generate(std::begin(some_array),
                  std::end(some_array),
                  [&eng,
                   dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(-5, +5)]() mutable -> int
    {
        return dist(eng);
    });
    handle_enemy(-1);
    handle_enemy(1);

    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
1?, 3?, 4?, 5?, 6?, 7?, 10?, 11?, 13?, 15?, 16?, 17?, 18?, 21?, 22?, 23?, 24?, 25?, 26?, 27?, 28?, 30?, 32?, 33?, 34?, 35?, 39?, 40?, 42?, 43?, 45?, 46?, 48?, 49?, 51?, 52?, 53?, 56?, 57?, 58?, 59?, 60?, 61?, 62?, 63?, 65?, 66?, 67?, 68?, 69?, 71?, 73?, 74?, 75?, 76?, 78?, 79?, 80?, 81?, 83?, 84?, 86?, 87?, 88?, 90?, 91?, 92?, 95?, 96?, 97?, 98?, 99?,
2!, 3!, 4!, 5!, 7!, 8!, 9!, 10!, 12!, 14!, 18!, 19!, 20!, 23!, 27!, 28!, 29!, 30!, 31!, 33!, 34!, 36!, 37!, 38!, 39!, 40!, 41!, 42!, 44!, 47!, 50!, 52!, 53!, 54!, 55!, 58!, 61!, 63!, 64!, 65!, 66!, 67!, 68!, 70!, 72!, 75!, 76!, 77!, 81!, 82!, 83!, 85!, 86!, 89!, 90!, 91!, 93!, 94!, 95!, 99!,
```

## But can we do better?

Well, I think it depends on how DRY you want to get, and how much you wish to decouple the rules from the logic.

This version defines an `actioner` class. The overloaded call operator will only compile for values of `enemy` that have a complete rule-set defined for them.

This may be to your liking. To my mind it starts to decouple the program so much that maintaining it may be a problem for anyone other than the author.

You might say that it's SuperDRY [thank you, I'm here all week :-)]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

void do_sth(int i) { std::cout << '!' ; }
void do_sth_else_here(int i) { std::cout << '?'; }

std::array<int, 100> some_array;

// a tag which turns an enemy value into a type, allowing us to easily tag-dispatch our rules.
template<int Enemy>
struct enemy_tag {
    static constexpr int value = Enemy;
};

// A function object that contains all the rules for this action
struct enemy_actioner
{
    constexpr enemy_actioner(std::array<int, 100> const& the_array)
    : _the_array(the_array)
    {}

    // Define logic once

    template<int Enemy, class Pred, class Action>
    void logic(Pred pred, Action action) const
    {
        for (int i = 1 ; i < _the_array.size() ; ++i)
        {
            if (pred(_the_array[i], Enemy))
            {
                std::cout << i;
                action(i);
                std::cout << ", ";
            }
        }
    }

    // Define Rules Once:

    static constexpr auto predicate_for(enemy_tag<1>) { return std::less_equal<>(); }
    static constexpr auto predicate_for(enemy_tag<-1>) { return std::greater_equal<>(); }

    static constexpr auto action_for(enemy_tag<1>) { return &do_sth; }
    static constexpr auto action_for(enemy_tag<-1>) { return do_sth_else_here; }

    // glue logic and rules together through the enemy_tag

    template<int Enemy>
    void operator()(enemy_tag<Enemy> enemy) const
    {
        logic<enemy.value>(predicate_for(enemy), action_for(enemy));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::array<int, 100> const& _the_array;
};


void handle_enemy(int enemy)
{
    // introduce our now opaque action object
    enemy_actioner action(some_array);

    // now all we need to do is turn the enemy integer into a tag and the actioner takes
    // care of all the rest. Truly DRY.
    switch (enemy)
    {
        case 1: return action(enemy_tag<1>());
        case -1: return action(enemy_tag<-1>());
        default: assert(!"logic error in program");
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::default_random_engine eng(std::random_device{}());
    std::generate(std::begin(some_array),
                  std::end(some_array),
                  [&eng,
                   dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(-5, +5)]() mutable -> int
                  {
                      return dist(eng);
                  });
    handle_enemy(-1);
    handle_enemy(1);

    return 0;
}
```